# View frame changing its position after i came back from another view [swift]

Tags: swift, view, frame

The menu view seems very nice everytime i open:

[image: menuview]

But everytime after i came back from another view, my menu view changing its position like this:

[image: menuview]

Why is it like this? i already set constraints at my storyboard, but still it become like this, how do i solve this?

Comment: how are you dismissing the views?

Comment: self.revealViewController().revealToggle(true)
        let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController")as! MenuViewController
        self.revealViewController().setFrontViewController(vc, animated: false)

Comment: Because i was using SWRevealViewController for my side menu view, so when user click the back button, i using this code

Comment: try to just dismiss the view controller don't reveal it. I believe the function is: [dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]

Comment: no, its not working

Comment: as in the function itself or the function works but it still doesn't work

Comment: i have to reveal it, because i have to reveal the side menu as well

Comment: i added the function inside, but when i clicked, it not functioning, nothing show up

Comment: how are you leaving other views? Are you doing it programmatically or through segues

Comment: ** [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; ** that would be the code to dismiss the current view to go back to the previous one. I had the wrong code in there before I believe :)

Comment: all i doing it programmatically. no, still not working

Comment: oh this is swift! My bad, in that case do self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true)

Comment: no, its still not working ;(

Comment: I'll check when I get home and I have access to my laptop ok!

Comment: what i can see, the right side top bar got changed. is it?

Comment: @cod3rite yes, that is the problem, and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: ok another thing? what inside that controller? tableview or scrollview? I saw there is uisearchbar

Comment: its a normal view, and on top is a top bar with back button and custom search bar, and also scroll view.

Comment: I added my answer, see if it works for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck this, to prevent auto adjust scroll view inset (as show in image).

[image]